# How to sum data to the current day in MDX

Tags: mdx

In my cube I have dimension calculated in the following way:

Sum(PeriodsToDate([Year].[Data].[(All)]), [Quantity])

how to change this formula to calculate the sum only to the current day?
The time dimension contains data on future years.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what you want to do, try the following:

For the sum from start until today:

```
SUM( { NULL : StrToMember('[Year].[Data].&[' + FORMAT(NOW(),'yyyyMMdd') +']') }, [Quantity] )
```

Depending on your representation of the day you may need to change the 'yyyyMMdd'-part of FORMAT, for me it is 20180321 for today as of writing this.

For the sum from start until the 'current' selected day (on the rows or the filter):

```
SUM( { NULL : [Year].[Data].currentmember }, [Quantity] )
```